# cabal exitfailure 77 on windows 64 platform

Tags: cabal-install, haskell-platform

cabal install tangaroa
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following will be installed:
network-2.6.3.1 (via: tangaroa-0.0.0.1 tangaroa-0.0.0.1 tangaroa-0.0.0.1 tangaroa-0.0.0.1) (new package)
tangaroa-0.0.0.1 (reinstall) (changes: QuickCheck-2.8.2 removed, cryptohash-sha256-0.11.100.0 added, directory-1.2.6.2 added, filepath-1.4.1.0 added, lifted-base-0.2.3.6 added, monad-control-1.0.1.0 added, monad-loops-0.4.3 added, random-1.1 added, stm-2.4.4.1 added, transformers-0.5.2.0 added)
Configuring network-2.6.3.1...
Failed to install network-2.6.3.1
Build log ( C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\network-2.6.3.1.log ):
Configuring network-2.6.3.1...
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler
checking build system type... bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
x86_64-pc-msys
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-msys
checking for gcc... D:\GHC-80~1.1Τ
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/cygdrive/c/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Temp/cabal-tmp-4120/network-2.6.3.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See`config.log' for more details
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-4120\network-2.6.3.1'

Answer (score 0):

As per the instructions on https://www.haskell.org/platform/ you need to configure your cabal to talk to the packaged msys distribution like so:

```
Modify your cabal config file (you can verify the location by running "cabal user-config init") to contain the following lines:
extra-prog-path: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.1\msys\usr\bin
extra-lib-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.1\mingw\lib
extra-include-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.
```